# Auto-update app with authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, enterprise, software-distribution

I have an enterprise-signed app that uses the "itms-services" protocol handler to automatically update that app if it determines that its out of date. Users can also connect to a website and install the app manually by clicking the link to the manifest file. I have password protection on the website so the users must authenticate before installing the app.

But I don't really want to force users to authenticate if the app is doing an automatic update. When an auto-update is triggered, the user is prompted to allow the install and then is prompted for id/password. I would like to eliminate the authentication if the app is already installed on a user's device. I have tried embedding the id/password in the manifest URL to the ipa file but the prompt still appears.

Does anyone know if this is possible?